# Creating webapp-runner.jar for Heroku in gradle

Tags: java, heroku, gradle

I have a gradle java project and I'm trying to get it running in Heroku. When I push it to Heroku, the start will crash:

```
[web.1]: no main manifest attribute, in build/libs/build_5a4de0d99cb0e389e770ac87d36d117e-0.0.1.war
[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

However, deploying the war directly will work:

```
heroku war:deploy build/libs/*.war --app ***

...

-----> Packaging application...
   - app: ***
   - including: webapp-runner.jar
   - including: build/libs/***.war
```

By googling I found out I should specify webapp-runner in Procfile, but so far I haven't been able to make one using gradle. How can I generate one, and how Heroku does it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like the following in your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.jsimone:webapp-runner:8.5.11.3'
}

task stage() {
    dependsOn clean, war
}
war.mustRunAfter clean

task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/server"
    from(configurations.compile) {
        include "webapp-runner*"
    }
}

stage.dependsOn(copyToLib)
```

For a full example, see [kissaten/gradle-webapp-runner](https://github.com/kissaten/gradle-webapp-runner)